# Downloading/Populating CSV File with SendFile

Tags: php, csv, yii

I am using the PHP Yii framework and trying to download my file. Currently, it downloads, but the file is populated with the `$filePath` location. Why doesn't this populate my file correctly?

```
$getData = // Getting data here.

$fileName = "file.csv";

$filePath = __Dir__ . "/.../exports";
$file = fopen($filePath . '' . $fileName, "w");
fputcsv($file, array_keys($getData[0]));
foreach ($getData as $row){
    fputcsv($file, $row);
}

    header("Content-Type: text/plain");
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename = $fileName");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    Yii::app()-> request -> sendFile($fileName, $filePath);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things. One, i think you are missing a `/` between `$filePath` and `$fileName` variables. Shouldn't it be something like:

```
$file = fopen($filePath . '/' . $fileName, "w");
```

Second, I think the way you are calling `sendFile()` is incorrect. The second parameter is not expected to be the path to the file. Rather, it is expected to be the actual content that should be sent to the browser. So try changing that line to something like:

```
Yii::app()->request->sendFile($fileName,  file_get_contents($filePath . '/' . $fileName));
```

Here, in the second parameter we are providing the contents of the file in the path specified by `$filePath . '/' . $fileName`.

Comment: haha, I was just adding my solution that I just found... I'll mark yours as the correct answer. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

After further research, I was able to solve my error. I needed to add `file_get_contents` instead of its actual path.

Original:

```
Yii::app()-> request -> sendFile($fileName, $filePath);
```

Modified:

```
Yii::app()-> request -> sendFile($fileName, file_get_contents($filePath . "/" . $fileName));
```